# Discord.js: AbortError: The user aborted a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been working on my ticket system and its transcript logging process, and one day this error started showing up and transcripts started to fail sending. This didn't use to be a thing before.
The full error is:

```js
[Error Handling System] Multiple Resolves
reject Promise {
  <rejected> AbortError: The user aborted a request.
      at abort (/PC/Bot/bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1448:16)
      at EventTarget.abortAndFinalize (/PC/Bot/bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1463:4)
      at EventTarget.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:460:20)
      at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:405:26)
      at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:97:10)
      at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:122:5)
      at Timeout.<anonymous> (/PC/Bot/bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:72:49)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
    type: 'aborted'
  }
}
```

My code is:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    interaction.channel.delete({ reason: `[Ticket System] Ticket Closed` }).then(async ch => {
      const mdb = require('./../models/tickets')
      mdb.findOne({ Channel: ch.id }, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data) {
          const openedBy = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(ch.topic.split(" ").splice(1).toString())
          fs.writeFileSync(`../${ch.name} - ${ch.id}.txt`, data.Content.join("\n\n"))
          let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Ticket Closed")
            .addField("<:ticket1:872962350473433089> Ticket Name", `${ch.name} (${ch.id})`)
            .addField(`<:person:890913045457563718> Opened By`, `${openedBy}`)
            .addField("<:admin:872930262516908113> Closed By", `${interaction.user} (${interaction.user.id})`)
            .addField(`<:open:914148680959934514> Open Time`, `<t:${moment(ch.createdTimestamp).format("X")}>`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({ text: `ID: ${uuidv4()}` })
          const atta = new Discord.MessageAttachment(fs.createReadStream(`../${ch.name}-${ch.id}.txt`))
          const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(transcripts_channel);
          logChannel.send({ embeds: [embed], files: [atta] })
          mdb.findOneAndDelete({ Channel: ch.id })
        }
      })
    })
  }, 10000)
```

I have tried removing MongoDB parts, tried decreasing the timeout and many more... None of those helped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

That's Discord API error, Discord receives a request from discord.js but takes too long to process so it's aborted. For more information this [issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3471) and this discord.js [pull request](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/3443).

Answer (score 1):

Tag from official discord.js server:

> `AbortError: The user aborted a request.`
> A request took longer than the specified restRequestTimeout (15 seconds default), and was aborted to not lock up the request handler.
> • This can be caused by an internal server error on Discord's side, or just a slow connection.
> • In case of a slow connection, the restRequestTimeout option in ClientOptions can be increased to prevent future AbortErrors.

Check that your internet is stable, and that Discord isn't having any issues [(status page)](https://discordstatus.com). Can you visit https://discord.com/app in your browser? Do you have a proxy or VPN enabled?

If it's still happening, you can try the second option, which is to change the `restRequestTimeout` in your Client constructor.

```js
const client = new Client({
  restRequestTimeout: 60000 // change the timeout to 1 minute
  // other options like your intents...
});
```

Comment: I don't have any VPN or proxy server connected. and when I change restRequestTimeout to 60s, it fails: `<rejected> HTTPError [FetchError]: request to https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/944709378773245962/messages failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
      ...
      at async TextChannel.send (/home/runner/874365837458/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
    code: 500,
    method: 'post',
    path: '/channels/944709378773245962/messages',
    requestData: { json: [Object], files: [Array] }
  }
}

Comment: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer): A connection was forcibly closed by a peer. This normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout or reboot. Commonly encountered via the http and net modules. - [node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#common-system-errors). Discord is working fine, so it's probably your computer or your internet. Do you have another computer/internet that you can try it on?